# EE1 -> EE2 Upgrade; Playa template tag conversion looks like it failed

Tags: ee2, playa, ee1, upgrade

Where before (in EE1) I had this in a template:

```
{assign_variable:current_weblog="news"}
...
{exp:weblog:entries ... }
    {reverse_related_entries weblog="{current_weblog}"}
    ...
    {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

After upgrading to EE 2.6.1 and installing Playa 4.4.3, I now have this (note the opening `{parents}` tag):

```
{preload_replace:current_channel="news"}
...
{exp:channel:entries ... }
    {parents }"}
    ...
    {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I haven't actually tested the template yet, but something tells me it's not gonna work... ;) I'm guessing that having the `weblog="{current_weblog}"` use an assigned variable (i.e. a curly-brace tag) rather than plain text is what tripped the converter up. In another template where the weblog was specified in plain text, this issue did not happen.

Any ideas, P&T? Thankfully, this is a trial upgrade on a *copy* of a live site, so it's not critically urgent. :)

Comment: Any chance this is on a publicly accessible server we could get CP/FTP access to?  If so, would you mind sending some credentials over to support@pixelandtonic.com?

Comment: Yuppers; info sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playa doesn’t actually convert your template code – the EE 2.6 upgrade does. Back before Playa 4, Playa just piggybacked on EE’s relationships system, and thus, used the same `{reverse_related_entries}` tag.

If you had just upgraded to Playa 4 but not upgraded EE, your templates would not have been messed with, and you would have had to go in and manually changed any `{reverse_related_entries}` tags to `{exp:playa:parents}`.

When you upgraded to EE 2.6, EE assumed that your `{reverse_related_entries}` tags were for Relationship fields, so it converted them to `{parents}` (or tried to, anyway). Changing those to `{exp:playa:parents}` tags should get your site back up and running.

Comment: That makes sense for the most part, but IIRC Playa 4 isn't EE1-compatible, only EE2. If that's correct, then there's no way for me to update Playa 3.1.2 (which is what the EE1 site is running) to Playa 4 before EE2's updater gets in there and messes things up.

Comment: Well either way you’ll have to go through your templates and change your `{reverse_related_entries}`/`{parents}` tags to `{exp:playa:parents}`. And technically you could do that before running the actual EE2 upgrade, so the EE 2.6 update script won’t make any changes.